# SMB/CIFS connection, attempting to change the permissionswithin rhel5 to comply with the clients needs

Tags: permissions, server-message-block, cifs

I can get the mount to work and as written in /etc/fstab:

//pcsprdvhost.prod.tsh.mis.mckesson.com/sftphome        /sftphome2            cifs    username=myuser,workgroup=domain,password=mypassword,noserverinfo,uid=tmadmin,gid=tibco,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 2

this means that every directory under /sftphome2 looks like:
drwxrwxrwx 1 tmadmin tibco 0 Jul  6  2010 D0000001

When I issue:
chown -R D0000001:D0000001_admin D0000001

Nothing happens.

When I pull the uid and gid specifications out I get the system owner/group of root:sys

What I need to be able to do is change the sub-directories under /sftphome2 to whatever owner and group (and permissions) I desire versus the ones that are getting specified.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Without the [Unix extensions](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/UNIX_Extensions) which you have disabled with the `nounix` option you can't do any ownership/permissions with CIFS.  Without the extensions the only thing you can do is set the ownership/permissions for the entire file-system. For the Unix extensions to work, they must be supported on the server you are connected to.  If these are not supported on your server, you may be out of luck.  You may need to look at using a different network filesystem.